# Jest: Share Variables Between Test Files

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'll start with an example of how I set up my tests for a backend server. **TL;DR at bottom**.

This file represents my server:

```js
//server.js
const express = require('express');

class BackendServer {
    constructor(backingFileDestination, database) {
        this.server = express();
        /* Set up server ... */
        /* Set up a mysql connection ... */
    }

    closeMySQLConnectionPool = () => {
        /* Close the mysql connection ... */
    };
}

module.exports = BackendServer;
```

In my `package.json`, I have the following:

```json
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.js"
  ]
}
```

Which allows me to use this setup file for my tests:

```js
//setupTests.js
const { endpointNames } = require('../../src/common/endpointNames.js');
const BackendServer = require('../server.js');
const server = new BackendServer(
    '../backing_files_test/',
    'test',
);
const supertester = require('supertest')(server.server);

// drop, recreate, and populate the database once before any tests run
beforeAll(async () => {
    await supertester.post(endpointNames.DROP_ALL_TABLES);
    await supertester.post(endpointNames.CREATE_ALL_TABLES);
    await supertester.post(endpointNames.POPULATE_ALL_TABLES);
});

// clean up the local setupTests server instance after all the tests are done
afterAll(async () => {
    await server.closeMySQLConnectionPool();
});
```

Notice how I had to import the `BackendServer` class and instantiate it, then use that instance of it.

Now, I have other test files, for example `test1.test.js`:

```js
//test1.test.js
const { endpointNames } = require('../../src/common/endpointNames.js');
const BackendServer = require('../server.js');
const server = new BackendServer(
    '../backing_files_test/',
    'test',
);
const supertester = require('supertest')(server.server);

// clean up the local server instance after all tests are done
afterAll(async () => {
    await server.closeMySQLConnectionPool();
});

test('blah blah', () => {
    /* Some test ... */
});
```

The problem is when I go to write `test2.test.js`, it will be the same as `test1.test.js`. This is the issue. For every test file, I need to instantiate a new server and then have a separate `afterAll()` call that cleans up that server's SQL connection. I can't stick that `afterAll()` inside of `setupTests.js` because it needs to operate on `test1.test.js`'s local `server` instance.

**TL;DR**: Each of my test files instantiates a new instance of my server. What I want is to instantiate the server once in `setupTests.js` and then simply use that instance in all my tests. Is there a good way to share this single instance between all my test files?

Comment: To be honest, even though repeating yourself is bad when programming, but when writing tests, repeating is not a bad thing, you don't have to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) when writing tests. Using a mutable shared state in your tests may cause confusing bugs because often time, you may forget to reset your state from previous tests when running new tests

Comment: @Teedeez Thank you for the insight. I agree that reusing mutable state without resetting between tests is probably a poor choice. However, it would still be nice to be able to accomplish the technical goal of the question whether it is preferred or not. I think, for example, using `beforeEach()` to reset and `afterAll()` to clean up all within `setupTests.js` is a nicer approach than having to put an `afterAll()` to clean up in each `.test.js` file.

Comment: @Teedeez another consideration is that as-is I need to run my tests with `--runInBand` because each `.test.js` file instantiates a new server which creates its own database connection. When the tests run simultaneously, weird things start to happen. With a shared database connection pool, I think that this won't be an issue and I can parallelize the tests again.

Comment: In Jest, you can turn off parallel execution, I've never had to do it, but it's possible, this way, your tests won't create simultaneous connections to the database

Comment: @Teedeez `--runInBand` is what turns off parallel execution.

Comment: I have come up with a solution for my own problem and posted an answer.

Comment: @TrashCan sure, but sometimes not sharing state between tests is just too slow.  That's why I'm here at least.  And in my case the lack of isolation in sharing state between tests isn't a problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to figure out a way to achieve what I wanted. It involves instantiating variables in `setupTests.js` and then exporting getters for them.

```js
//setupTests.js
const { endpointNames } = require('../../src/common/endpointNames.js');
const BackendServer = require('../server.js');
const server = new BackendServer(
    '../backing_files_test/',
    'test',
);
const supertester = require('supertest')(server.server);

// drop, recreate, and populate the database once before any tests run
beforeAll(async () => {
    await supertester.post(endpointNames.DROP_ALL_TABLES);
    await supertester.post(endpointNames.CREATE_ALL_TABLES);
    await supertester.post(endpointNames.POPULATE_ALL_TABLES);
});

// clean up the local setupTests server instance after all the tests are done
afterAll(async () => {
    await server.closeMySQLConnectionPool();
});

const getServer = () => { //        <==== ADD THESE 2 FUNCTIONS
    return server;
};

const getSupertester = () => { //   <==== ADD THESE 2 FUNCTIONS
    return supertester;
};

module.exports = { getServer, getSupertester }; //   <==== EXPORT THEM
```

I added a couple functions to the end of `setupTests.js` that, when called, will return whatever the local variables point to at the time. In this case, `server` and `supertester` are declared with `const`, so I could have exported them directly I think, but in other cases I had some variables that I wanted to share that were declared with `let`, so I left it this way.

Now I have functions exported from `setupTests.js` that I can import in my test files like this:

```js
//test1.test.js
const { endpointNames } = require('../../src/common/endpointNames.js');
const { getServer, getSupertester } = require('./setupTests.js');

test('blah blah', () => {
    /* Some test using getSupertester().post() or getServer().someFunction() ... */
});
```

So now I can have local variables inside `setupTests.js` that are accessible in my `.test.js` files.

This makes my whole testing process cleaner because I only need to set up and tear down one server, which means only 1 connection pool for my SQL server and less code duplication of having to instantiate and clean up a new server in every `.test.js` file.

Cheers.

Comment: how is it working? i'm getting error that globalSetup must return a function. This is done in globalSetup file. Then i tried to do so in steupFile also:
const STORAGE = {};
const get = (key) => STORAGE;
const set = (key, value) => {
    STORAGE[key] = value;
    console.log('after setting ', STORAGE);
};

module.exports = {
    get,
    set
}
but still it wont work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "globalSetup must return a function." Perhaps you can post a new question or provide more details about your situation.

Comment: What if instead of a class to create a server, I have an async function that creates it ? I cannot use await in the outer most scope.

Comment: In that case you would likely have to use a `then` call. You could do something like `const myServerPromise = createMyServer();`. You can probably export this promise and then later on when you want to use the server object, `myServerPromise.then((server) => { /* ... */ });`. But you may want to post a separate question with additional details if you have some difficulty with getting this to work.